# Link to the Google Contacts page with the focus on the search box?

Tags: google-contacts

Is there an address that will open the 'Google Contact' page with the focus on the search field so that I can directly start typing the name of the contact I'm looking for?  [This](https://mail.google.com/mail/?hl=en&zx=x1cm52yazd7i&shva=1#contacts) opens the page, but the focus is not to the search field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that you can do that, unless there is a script for that. But you can simply press the `/` to send the focus to the search box (`?` for more shortcuts).